# Regular semiring (in the sense of von Neumann)

Tags: abstract-algebra, semiring

A semiring $R$ is called regular (in the sense of von Neumann) if for each $a\in R$, there exists $x, y\in R$ such that $a+axa=aya.$

[Reference here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://kmj.knu.ac.kr/journal/download_pdf.php%3Fspage%3D1%26volume%3D44%26number%3D1&ved=2ahUKEwj4lbmiv4rkAhWbf30KHfaEBOsQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2_xCn8xOnYrrp3pMHJ6VS_)

Further, from the above link, I encounter that the semiring $\langle \Bbb Z_+ \cup \{0\}, \max, \cdot \rangle$ of non-negative integers with usual multiplication and $a+b=\max\lbrace a, b \rbrace$, is a regular semiring in the above sense. But I think this will be possible only if we take $x=y=1$. Now my question is: is taking $x=y$ in the above definition a valid consideration or not?

Comment: The link to your reference is broken.

Comment: There’s no requirement that $x\ne y$ in the definition

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken. Anyways, the title of the reference provided is 'A note on regularity in matrix semirings'- Authored by Shamik Ghosh. Moreover, this reference is not absolutely required in this problem. @egreg, seems to have pointed right.

Comment: Yes choosing $x = y = 1$ is not a problem. Your definition does not require $x, y$ to be distinct.

Comment: Also, if $a$ is positive integer strictly greater than $1$, then $x = y$ **has to be true**. Also they cannot equal $0$ but other than that you are free to choose any $x, y$ you want. Finally, if $a = 0$ or $a = 1$, then you have other choices for $x, y$, not necessarily equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the natural numbers (zero included) it holds $a\le a^2$, so taking $x=y=1$ is perfectly right.